# Insertion of a python list items into MySQL table line by line

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping

I have the following web scraping program for practice purpose but I have decided to take it further by inserting the list items into a MySQL Database table that has Long_Text data type columns but I keep getting an error. I have tried different methods and even converting the list to dataframes (as you can see below) but still the same.

Here is the snippet for the list and the dataframe:

```
period_tags = seven_day_fc.select(".tombstone-container .period-name")
period = [pt.get_text() for pt in period_tags]
period_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(period).reshape(-1,1), columns = list("p"))
```

and here is my insertion statement:

```
cnx = MySQLConnection(**dbconfig)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
insert_wData = "INSERT INTO weather_data_scrape (period) VALUES (%s)" % (period_df)
cursor.execute(insert_wData)
cnx.commit()
cnx.close()
```

This is the print result of Period list:

```
['Today', 'Tonight', 'Wednesday', 'WednesdayNight', 'Thursday', 'ThursdayNight', 'Friday', 'FridayNight', 'Saturday']
```

and this is the print out of the Period df:

```
0           Today
1         Tonight
2       Wednesday
3  WednesdayNight
4        Thursday
5   ThursdayNight
6          Friday
7     FridayNight
8        Saturday
```

and this is the error message:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0
>   Today
>       1         Tonight
>       2       Wednesday
>       3  WednesdayNight
>       4       ' at line 2

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Probably you want to convert  period_df to string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function to_sql :

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

```
period_df.to_sql('weather_data_scrape', cnx , if_exists='append')
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. So, the parameter, 'weatber_data_scrape' needs to be replaced with the variable name of my data frame?

Comment: No the variable name of your data frame is before the .to_sql

Comment: Oh sorry. That was totally dumb of me. Didn't pay attention to that. That's the table name. Got it. I will give it a try and let you know.